# Nativescript question marshalling with Interface

Tags: javascript, nativescript

How can I translate the following code into Javascript?

The complete code is in https://www.mercadopago.com.mx/developers/en/guides/payments/mobile-checkout/receive-payments/

The doubt is that an interface is needed to be able to implement it in the class, I have already implemented it but it still does not work.

What happens is that I need to implement the finishCheckout and cancelCheckout methods with the PXLifeCycleProtocol interface within the

```js
checkout.startWithNavigationControllerLifeCycleProtocol (
                app.ios.rootController,
                null // Here PXLifeCycleProtocol Interface
            );
```

In the part of the null, and I do not know how to implement those methods

```
- (IBAction)startMercadoPagoCheckout:(id)sender {
  MercadoPagoCheckout *checkout = [[MercadoPagoCheckout alloc] initWithBuilder:[[MercadoPagoCheckoutBuilder alloc] initWithPublicKey:@"ENV_PUBLIC_KEY" preferenceId:@"PREFERENCE_ID"]];
  [checkout startWithNavigationController:self.navigationController lifeCycleProtocol:self];
}

-(void (^ _Nullable)(void))cancelCheckout {
    return ^ {
        [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    };
}

- (void (^)(id<PXResult> _Nullable))finishCheckout {
    return nil;
}
```

My code:

```js
import { Common } from "./mercadopago-px.common";
import * as app from "tns-core-modules/application";

export class MercadopagoPx extends Common {
    public start(publicKey: string, preferenceId: string): Promise<any> {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let checkout = MercadoPagoCheckout.alloc().initWithBuilder(
                MercadoPagoCheckoutBuilder.alloc()
                    .initWithPublicKeyPreferenceId(publicKey, preferenceId)
                    .setLanguage("es")
            );

            checkout.startWithNavigationControllerLifeCycleProtocol(
                app.ios.rootController,
                null // Here PXLifeCycleProtocol Interface
            );

            // but I do not know how to implement it with the self
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate, what you mean by "it still does not work". It doesn't show the new view controller Or it throws any error? Do you have any error log? Also instead of `app.ios.rootController` try `frame.topmost().currentPage.ios`.

Comment: What happens is that I need to implement the finishCheckout and cancelCheckout methods with the PXLifeCycleProtocol interface within the checkout.startWithNavigationControllerLifeCycleProtocol (
                app.ios.rootController,
                null // Here PXLifeCycleProtocol Interface
            );

In the part of the null, and I do not know how to implement those methods

Comment: [Here](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/ios-runtime/how-to/ObjC-Subclassing#typescript-delegate-example) is how you will implement delegate.